# Tensorflow2 For loop Graph Execution Valuerror

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am using TF2 for hyperparameter optimization. For example, I define a range of learning rates `lr= [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01]` to pass into a `Trainer` function which includes a custom training loop (using `Gradientape`). However, I met error when I use `@tf.function`. My training structure is like this:

```
def Trainer(lr):
    
    # Define the optimizer
    optim = tf.keras.optimizers.experimental.Nadam(learning_rate=lr)
    
    train_dataset, test_dataset, sample_size = dataset_load(arg)
    
    # define model
    model_config = {arg}
    net = Mymodel(model_config)
    step = 0
    with tqdm.tqdm(total=max_step, leave=True, desc='Training') as pbar:
        while step < max_step:
            for signal in train_dataset:
                
                # Calculate loss
                loss = train_batch(signal and other parameter)
    
                step += 1
                pbar.update()
                pbar.set_postfix(
                    {'loss': loss.numpy(),
                     'step': step})
```

The `train_batch` function is:

```
@tf.function 
def train_batch(signal, arg...):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        tape.watch(model.trainable_variables)
        loss = compute_loss([signal], model)
    grad = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables,
                         unconnected_gradients=tf.UnconnectedGradients.ZERO)
    optim.apply_gradients(
        zip(grad, model.trainable_variables))
    del grad

    return loss
```

For the outer loop, I  define the `lr`, then use:
for lr_current in lr:
Trainer(lr)

The program executes normally for the first `lr_current`. But when the outer for loop goes to the second value of `lr_current`, the error comes out:

> ValueError: tf.function only supports singleton tf.Variables created
> on the first call. Make sure the tf.Variable is only created once or
> created outside tf.function.

I do not understand why this error comes out. I think it is related to the for loop of `Trainer` function. I also tried to `del net` when finishing the training but it did not work. The program runs normally for all `lr_current` when I removed `@tf.function`.

I have uploaded a [minimal reproducible example](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1GNh-OhyR5LE52KbOXdqo7K4yuy1IhutX?usp=sharing) to the Colab. Could anyone help me out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The thing is when you are using `@tf.function()` it converts your inputs and all your operations into a graph but before it makes a graph it first observes the input shapes and types then it makes a variable for it for tracing, now the problem is it only makes it for the first iteration because making variables in each iteration is not feasible. So, the problem is in your compute loss function. share its code. your code is calling some function which is outside from the scope of graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done your work, copy this code and run it into your notebook.

```
def Trainer():

    # loss_func = tf.keras.losses.RootMeanSquaredError()


    train_dataset, test_dataset, sample_size = dataset_load(time_len=100, batch_size=16)

    epoch = 0
    step = 0
    with tqdm.tqdm(total=10, leave=True, desc='Training') as pbar:
        while epoch < 10:
            for signal in train_dataset:
                obs_signal, obs_mask, impute_mask = genmask(signal=signal, missing_ratio=0.2,
                                                            missing_type='rm')
                # Calculate loss
                loss = train_batch(signal=obs_signal, obs_mask=obs_mask,
                                   impute_mask=impute_mask)

                step+=1
                pbar.set_postfix(
                    {'loss': loss.numpy(),
                     'step': step,
                     'epoch': epoch})
                
            epoch += 1
            pbar.update()

def compute_loss(signal_mask: List, diff_params):
    obs_mask = signal_mask[1]
    impute_mask = signal_mask[2]
    # [B, T], [B, T]
    epsilon_theta, eps = diffusion(signal_mask, diff_params)
    # MSE loss
    target_mask = obs_mask - impute_mask
    residual = (epsilon_theta - eps) * target_mask

    loss = tf.reduce_sum(residual**2)/ (tf.reduce_sum(target_mask)
                                        if tf.reduce_sum(target_mask)>0 else 1.0)
    return loss

def diffusion(signal_mask: List, diff_params, eps=None):

    assert len(signal_mask) == 3

    signal = signal_mask[0]
    cond_mask = signal_mask[2]

    B, L, C = signal.shape[0], signal.shape[1], signal.shape[2]  # B is batchsize, C=1, L is signal length
    _dh = diff_params
    T, Alpha_bar = _dh["T"], _dh["Alpha_bar"]
    timesteps = tf.random.uniform(
        shape=[B, 1, 1], minval=0, maxval=T, dtype=tf.int32)  # [B], randomly sample diffusion steps from 1~T

    if eps is None:
        eps = tf.random.normal(tf.shape(signal))  # random noise

    extracted_alpha = tf.gather(Alpha_bar, timesteps)
    transformed_X = tf.sqrt(extracted_alpha) * signal + tf.sqrt(
        1 - extracted_alpha) * eps  # compute x_t from q(x_t|x_0)
    timesteps = tf.cast(timesteps, tf.float32)
    total_input = tf.stack([cond_mask * signal,
                            (1 - cond_mask) * transformed_X], axis=-1)  # B, L, K, 2
    obser_tp = tf.range(signal.shape[1])

    epsilon_theta = net(
        (total_input, obser_tp, cond_mask,
         tf.squeeze(timesteps, axis=-1)))  # predict \epsilon according to \epsilon_\theta

    return epsilon_theta, eps


def dataset_load(time_len, batch_size):

    train_data = np.random.randn(batch_size*10, time_len, 10)
    test_data = np.random.randn(batch_size, time_len, 10)
    shuffle_size_train = train_data.shape[0]

    train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset. \
        from_tensor_slices(train_data).shuffle(shuffle_size_train) \
        .batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True)
    test_dataset = tf.convert_to_tensor(test_data)
    L = train_data.shape[-2]
    K = train_data.shape[-1]

    return (train_dataset, test_dataset, [L, K])

def genmask(signal: tf.Tensor, missing_ratio, missing_type):
    """Generate the mask
    Returns:
        observed_values (tf.Tensor): [B, T, K], [B, T, K], multivariate time series with K features
        observed_masks (tf.Tensor): [B, T, K], mask for observation points
        impute_mask (tf.Tensor): [B, T, K], mmask for imputation target
    """
    miss_ratio = missing_ratio
        
    observed_values = signal.numpy().astype(np.single)
    observed_mask = ~np.isnan(observed_values)

    rand_for_mask = np.random.rand(*observed_mask.shape) * observed_mask
    rand_for_mask = rand_for_mask.reshape(len(rand_for_mask), -1) # B, L*K
    for i in range(len(observed_mask)): # Loop for Batch
        sample_ratio = np.random.rand() if not missing_ratio else missing_ratio # missing ratio
        num_observed = observed_mask[i].sum()
        num_masked = round(num_observed * sample_ratio)
        rand_for_mask[i][np.argpartition(rand_for_mask[i], -num_masked)[-num_masked:]] = -1
    gt_masks = (rand_for_mask > 0).reshape(observed_mask.shape).astype(np.single)
    observed_mask = observed_mask.astype(np.single)
    
    return observed_values, observed_mask, gt_masks
@tf.function
def train_batch(signal, obs_mask, impute_mask):
    """Warpped training on a batch using static graph.
    Args:
        signal (tf.Tensor): [B, T, K], multivariate time series with K features
        obs_mask (tf.Tensor): [B, T, K], mask for observation points
        impute_mask (tf.Tensor): [B, T, K], mask for imputation target
    Returns:
        loss (float): average loss function of on a batch
    """
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        tape.watch(net.trainable_variables)
        loss = compute_loss([signal, obs_mask, impute_mask],
                                 diffusion_hyperparams)

    grad = tape.gradient(loss, net.trainable_variables,
                         unconnected_gradients=tf.UnconnectedGradients.ZERO)
    optim.apply_gradients(
        zip(grad, net.trainable_variables))
    del grad

    return loss


lr = [0.001, 0.002, 0.01]
for lr_iter in lr:
    optim = tf.keras.optimizers.experimental.Nadam(lr_iter)
    model_config = { "res_channels": 64}
    net = mymodel(model_config)
    diffusion_hyperparams = calc_diffusion_hyperparams(T=50, beta_0=0.0001, beta_T=0.5, strategy="quadratic")
    Trainer()
    tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
    del net
```

Link to the Notebook

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1uh3-q3hM4obKLbh93sfT25zoUbK4jfUJ?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I am a bit confused. When I finished the execution of each iteration: send `lr_current` to the `Trainer` function and do training etc.  The model should be released and variables should not exist any more. So could you tell me the mechanism of my error??

Comment: The problem is you were sending the whole model to the function as `@tf.function` enables the graph execution, but before making a graph it first trace the size and type of the variables, but you were passing it the class variable, so it was making those variables again in the 2nd iteration. I make the model variable global, therefore before going to the next iteration first you have to release the model from the memory, as it is now global.